# MySQL query cause error: ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql

```
    wquery = """UPDATE `cin`.`flags` SET `flag`='%s', `update_time`='%d' WHERE `name`='%s' AND `lockid`='%s'"""
    cursor.execute(wquery, (pic_bin, update_time, cname, lockid,))
    cnx.commit()
```

This code cause : ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting

tried many way but can't find solution... :(

Any ideas ?

Comment: why are you using quotation marks?

Comment: to properly execute the query as it can result in error when not used depending the server where query is executed...

Comment: No, it's wrong to use quotes here, these will be added by the library automatically if appropriate. `'%s'` would be converted to `''some_parameter''` for a string (vulnerable to sql injection!). Also, don't use `%d` use `%s` only, all paramerters will be converted to strings internally before applying the format.

Comment: Thanks Mata! Now working... first time it work without quotes... is it due to the fact that vars are not formated in wquery ?